# Blitting with OpenCL

Tags: c, opengl, interop, opencl, gpu

I am making an OpenCL raycaster, and I'm looking to blit pixels to the screen with the less overhead possible (Every tick counts), as low than calling glClear() every tick, I thought of creating a framebuffer to draw to and passing it to OpenCL, and then blitting with glBlitFramebuffer() but I think that automatically drawing to screen is way better, so there, is there a way to draw pixels with openCL ? Hacky stuff are OK

The best thing I can do now is check out how glClear does it ...

Answer (score 7):

The usual approach is to use OpenCL to draw to a shared OpenGL/OpenCL texture object (created with the `clCreateFromGLTexture()` function) and then draw it to the screen with OpenGL by rendering a full-screen quad with that texture.

Edit: I've written a small example which uses OpenCL to calculate a mandelbrot fractal and then renders it directly from the GPU to the screen with OpenGL. The code is here: [mandelbrot.cpp](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/blob/develop/example/mandelbrot.cpp).

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I'm curious, would using a renderbuffer be faster than you method? +Do I need to clear the screen ?